# Use of Task Definition in AWS | Configure Hazelcast to run on AWS

Tags: java, amazon-ec2, hazelcast

I'm a Java developer, aware of AWS and good at Hazelcast independently.

Have 2 AWS EC2 instances running and would like to run Hazelcast as an in-memory cluster between nodes. Followed [link](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-aws) to do the required changes. Except configuration for `taskdef.json` in Task Definition.

Read some documentation but couldn't understand what and why exactly task definition is?

How to i know if it's already created? else if I create one now, would my production gets distracted?

Comment: Are you trying to deploy on EC2 or ECS? If not ECS then you dont need taskdef.json.

Comment: @wildnez Its EC2 not ECS. But couldn't establish the cluster.

Comment: How are you establishing that the cluster is not getting formed? Members list? One of the most common mistake users make is not check if their ec2 instances are reachable by each other. Can you check that too?

Comment: @wildnez Yes. Both the instances were able to ping each other. I'm using this <tcp-ip enabled="true">
                <interface>10.0.0.*</interface> 
                 <interface>127.0.0.1</interface>
                <member-list>
                    <member>ip1</member>
                    <member>1p2</member>
                </member-list>
            </tcp-ip>

Comment: So you are not using EC2 discovery, you are using TCP discovery. Correct documentation for tcp is http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.8.3/manual/html-single/index.html#discovering-members-by-tcp

Comment: Also, are those IP addresses private or public?

Comment: mentioned private and public Ip addresses in members.

Answer (score 0):

The whole reason for the ec2 discovery is to resolve the issue with non static ip addresses. The EC2 plugin performs a describe instances and pulls the ip adddress from the json.